# DynamoDBMapper: Query on Multiple Conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Assume my data structure has several data members

```
class Data {
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    String id;

    String id1;

    String id2; 

    ....
}
```

Now I want to do query based on `id1` and `id2`, like SQL `where id1 ="id1" and id2 = "id2"`. I know somehow I should make them as global secondary key like either way below:

- Make id1 and id2 as different indexes like this:

  ```
  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "INDEX_ID1")
  String id1;

  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "INDEX_ID2")
  String id2;

  //And then do query it by any of the index name:
  DynamoDBQueryExpression<Data> query = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Data>()
              .withIndexName("INDEX_ID1") //or INDEX_ID2 here
              .withConsistentRead(false)  //GSIs do not support consistent reads
              .withKeyConditionExpression("id1 = :id1 AND id2 = :id2")
              .withExpressionAttributeValues(ImmutableMap.of(":id1", new AttributeValue(id1), ":id2", new AttributeValue(id2)));
  ```
- Make id1 and id2 as partition key and sort key under same index name:

  ```
  @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "INDEX_ID1_ID2")
  String id1;

  @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "INDEX_ID1_ID2")
  String id2;

  //And then do query it by the only index name:
  DynamoDBQueryExpression<Data> query = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Data>()
              .withIndexName("INDEX_ID1_ID2")
              .withConsistentRead(false)  //GSIs do not support consistent reads
              .withKeyConditionExpression("id1 = :id1 AND id2 = :id2")
              .withExpressionAttributeValues(ImmutableMap.of(":id1", new AttributeValue(id1), ":id2", new AttributeValue(id2)));
  ```

Which way is right or better?

Besides, if  I want to query based on more than two conditions (say there is a id3), then how can I do that?

Comment: You can always scan the entire table and filter out based on conditions. But if you have complex queries on many attributes like it sounds then maybe DynamoDB is not suited for your need.

Answer (score 0):

1. > Make id1 and id2 as different indexes like this

In this, you can't query on both `id1` and `id2`, you can only query on one. That is because DynamoDB doesn't allow you to use two different indexes simultaneously.

2. > Make id1 and id2 as partition key and sort key under same index name

This will work for SQL-like `where id1 ="id1" and id2 = "id2"` queries. But the approach won't scale if you add another `id`, because you can only have one partition-key and one sort-key.

As mentioned in a comment above, you can `Scan` for more filters and conditions. But if you think you'll need lot more complexities in future, DynamoDB might not be the right tool for you.